# Google AppEngine Datastore admin tool authentication error

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-datastore

When I try to open the google appengine datastore admin tool it redirects me to:

https://ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-myapp.appspot.com/_ah/login_required?continue=https://ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-myapp.appspot.com/_ah/datastore_admin%3Fapp_id%3Dmyappid

and gives me a 500 error.

According to this appengine bug report:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10150&q=%22datastore%20admin%22&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

"This looks to be a problem because you are using non-default authentication scheme.

Are you using user service/Google Accounts API for authentication of users inside your application? If not, consider changing your authentication method.

If you are, then you'll need to setup a custom domain and access the datastore admin via:
https://ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-
so that the correct authentication cookies can be used."

I'm using simpleauth for authentication and have a custom domain with an ssl certificate.

I would love to be able to backup my datastore data, it's a pretty big risk for my site if I can't!

Any ideas?

Comment: In the past, I had problems that were caused by third party cookies being off and turning on third party cookies allowed me to access datastore admin.  I don't have this problem now (I can access datastore admin with third party cookies off), but worth a try to see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. I wonder if any companies actually use app engine commercially. I'm using it because it is free. I would never use it commercially because the support is absolutely woeful

Comment: well, if I create a new App Engine application and copy my app to it, then the datastore admin functionality works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must have been a problem on Googles end, because when I tried again a few months later it magically worked.